# Как записать в массив все емейлы, которые встречаются в строке?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка `$str` достаточно большого объема. Нужно записать в массив `$arr` ВСЕ емейлы, которые встречаются в строке `$str`, с учетом того, что емейлы бывают не только вида `aaa@bbb.ru`, но и `aaa.bbb@ccc.ddd.ru` и т.п.

Спасибо огромное заранее! Сам с регулярками не дружу.

Comment: /^([a-z0-9_-]+\.)*[a-z0-9_-]+@[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/

Вот это как раз и таких: aaa.bbb@ccc.ddd.ru пропустит.
На всякий случай если подружите с регулярками.

Comment: @bemulima, проверил через http://regex101.com. Не работает.

Comment: @jackair, из любого фреймворка заберите.

Comment: @VasyOk, думаю, если бы я умел это делать, то сделал бы и не писал вопрос здесь.

Comment: Говорят, что для правильного разбора нужен [вот такой регэсп](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Не думаю, что использовать регулярные выражения для выделения e-mail адресов это здравая мысль.

Можете почитать вот [эту тему](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address).

Comment: @avp, в итоге моя задача, просто вытащить все емелы из строки. Как это сделать более "здраво" нежели через регулярки? PS. примеры из ваших ссылок тоже не работают корректно. повторюсь: мне НЕ нужен валидатор. Мне нужно спарсить ВСЕ емейлы из строки. Строка содержит не тлько емейлы, но и лишний текст

Comment: читал статью, что регулярки не могут полностью выбрать емейлы, или выберут с багами, думаю строка не особо длинная - перебор = наше всё)))))

Comment: @jackair, из произвольного текста не выбирал, а разбор строк, состоящих из e-mail (TO, CC, BCC из заголовков текста письма) в массивы с ними на Си когда-то писал.  
Помнится, парсер (в соответствии с RFC, не на регулярках) потянул на несколько сот строчек.

Во что это выльется на PHP, не знаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так: :)

```
$string = 'тут много текста mail1@mail.ru тут еще текст mail2@mail.ru и там еще текст mail3@mail.ru';

preg_match_all('#([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)#is', $string, $output);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

Пример работы http://ideone.com/kAewMn

Comment: @Bastian, посмотрите примеры адресов хотя бы [вот тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)  
Самых экзотических как допустимых, так и недопустимых там, правда, я не нашел, но и приведенных:
  
    abc."defghi".xyz@example.com  
    jsmith@[IPv6:2001:db8::1]  
    john.smith@(comment)example.com  эквивалентно john.smith@example.com  

уже более чем достатчно.

Comment: @avp такие email адреса уже слишком экзотические, и считать их вообще за таковые это уже за гранью моего понимания. Извиняйте, но я даже кириллических адресов еще не встречал у кого либо.

Comment: Поэтому в современном софте наблюдается все больше глюков?

Comment: @avp не задаюсь таким вопросом, и, наверное, потому что он меня не особо интересует. :)

Comment: @Bastian, Ваш вариант работает, Благодарю!